# why dont i have to declare the variable in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, scope, computer-science

in javascript, why are we able to use variables that havent been declared (i.e. const, let, var) in the for loop? example code below:

```js
function testFunc(items) {
    for (item of items) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

I would expect the above code to error out. Dont we need to declare the variable with one of the **const**, **let** and **var** keywords? Example below:

```js
function testFunc(items) {
    for (const item of items) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In non-strict mode, it will not throw an error. It will just create a global variable `item` for the window:

```js
function testFunc(items) {
    for (item of items) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}
testFunc([1,2,3])
console.log(window.item) //property created in the window object
console.log(item) //global variable
```

Even though you cannot get the value of `item` before it's assigned (ReferenceError), if you have an assignment like `item=1` in non-strict mode, it will create a variable (global scope) if it's not yet defined. The for loop in this case does the `item=1`, `item=2`, `item=3`. So, getting the value of the `item` (as in `console.log(item)`) is allowed.
 And as you can see from the output, the value of `item` after the loop is `3`.

---

But if you just add a "use strict" statement, it throws an error

```js
"use strict"
function testFunc(items) {
    for (item of items) {
        console.log(item)
    }
}
testFunc([1,2,3]) //throws ReferenceError
```